# RewriteRule for specific Query String

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I’d like to use .htaccess to rewrite a URL like this

`https://example.com/pages/games/demons-souls/?page=mods`

to look like this

`https://example.com/games/demons-souls/mods`

I managed to hide the pages folder in the URL with this code:

```
Options +MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

# Rewrite "/games/<anything>" to "/pages/games/<anything>"
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/pages/games
RewriteRule ^games($|/.*) pages/$0
```

But I need a proper RewriteRule for the Query String. I tried this but it didn’t work ...

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ $1/index.php?page=$2 [L,QSA]
```

I’d really appreciate some help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have it like this:

```sh
Options +MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

# Rewrite "/games/<foo>/<bar>" to "/pages/games/<foo>/?page=<bar>"
RewriteRule ^(games/[\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ pages/$1/?page=$2 [L,NC,QSA]

# Rewrite "/games/<anything>" to "/pages/games/<anything>"
RewriteRule ^games($|/.*) pages/$0 [L,NC]
```

Comment: Hey, thank you, man. It works perfectly. I wanted to add that I discovered this RewriteRule of mine `RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ $1/index.php?page=$2 [L,QSA]` also works if you put it in a new .htaccess file located directly inside the _game_ subfolder. 

It would be here: /pages/games/.htaccess.

I just wanted people to know.